# How can make a single get request for different sets of data?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 action which returns json data.

The first action is called with an ajax request to fill the first set of controls which remains common for the whole project but has to be filled on each menu click but the lower part of the page is variable and needs to be filled with different data.

Now what I want is to send a single request and do the 2 things in 1 get request.

```
public JSONRESULT GetCommonData()
{
    return JSONDATA;
}

public JSONRESULT GetVariableData()
{
    return JSONDATA;
}
```

Now a single ajax call should be able to do this without sending the request for 2nd set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a view model and you can return both 2 data in a single action. On the action you can get variables as you want.

```
public class JsonResult
{
    public object CommonData { get; set; }
    public object VariableData { get; set; }
}
```

If you will have some relational data you might get circular reference error. You can use it like this:

```
var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(yourmodel, Formatting.Indented,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
    });

return Json(jsonResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```